# Button with properties set in code-behind not firing click event

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

When setting the translationX and translationY of a button in the code-behind, its click events aren't fired: the button doesn't seem to be able to be clicked. The buttons are part of a StackLayout and I have used x:Name to access them from the code-behind!

The buttons properties except for the translations are set in the XAML, the formers are set like so:

```
element.TranslationX = array[i].xPos;
element.TranslationY = array[i].yPos;
```

**UPDATE**

Code-Behind

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;

        CircleLayout(132.0, Math.PI, 7, "menuGrid");
    }

    public void CircleLayout(double r, double theta, int nbElements, String currentMenu)
    {
        CircleObject[] array = new CircleObject[nbElements];

        for (int i = 1; i < nbElements; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                array[i] = new CircleObject(r * Math.Sin(theta), r * Math.Cos(theta));
            } else
            {
                theta += (Math.PI / 180) * 360 / nbElements;
                array[i] = new CircleObject(r * Math.Sin(theta), r * Math.Cos(theta));
            }

            StackLayout element = this.FindByName<StackLayout>(currentMenu + i);
            element.TranslationX = array[i].xPos;
            element.TranslationY = array[i].yPos;
        }
    }

    public class CircleObject
    {
        public double xPos;
        public double yPos;

        public CircleObject(double x, double y)
        {
            xPos = x;
            yPos = y;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Example of a button in XAML

```
<StackLayout x:Name="menuGrid0">
        <Button x:Name="button"
                BackgroundColor="#FF6633"
                CornerRadius="70"
                HeightRequest="65"
                WidthRequest="65"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label x:Name="textDetection"
               Text="D E T E C T I O N"
               FontSize="9"
               TextColor="#FF6633"
               HeightRequest="10"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide the complete button on xaml and method from code behind ?

Comment: @FabriBertani I just updated the thread with the code!

Comment: 3 points: 1) you do not want to be subscribing in XAML and in code. I would remove the Clicked event subscription from the code. 2) there is nothing inside your example click event handler, I assume there is in your actual implementation that you are able to test? 3) Is there any chance you are rendering something over the top to prevent the button clicks from being registered?

Comment: @Bijington Oops yes sorry, I usually do not subscribe from both code and XAML, but forgot to edit it out (I was trying several ways to see if it would work). But yes there is some body in the event handler! Decided to omit it out to avoid the code to be too heavy for you guys to read. I am not rendering anything else over the frames, and I am sure of it since I used to set all buttons in a grid, and they worked fine. In this case, the buttons do not seem to be clicked at all (the buttons' color do not change when tapped).

Comment: @StellaNguyen if the buttons color does not change when tapped (what about hovering over?) then it is likely something is displaying on top, or the StackLayout isn't big enough. If you are running on UWP then I would suggest using the inspector tools (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/07/live-visual-tree-in-visual-studio-3/) to work out what is preventing the mouse clicks. I am happy to be corrected but as I remember it `Grid`s resize to their contents whereas `StackLayouts` do not.